# iOS app calling redirected domain

Tags: ios, json, web

I'm creating rest based app and when I make requests to server url:
Example : 107.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080/taxi - it`s working, returns me JSON.
But when I make request to domain forwarded to that ip my app shows me that exception:

```
2017-04-18 20:23:53.063 Project X[4121:301275] http://107.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080/taxi  
2017-04-18 20:23:53.065 Project X[4121:301275] fireGetWebserviceCall finally  
2017-04-18 20:23:53.252 Project X[4121:301275] Error: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: not found (404)" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x600000240600 {Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1016 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html" UserInfo={com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response= { URL: http://107.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080/taxi } { status code: 404, headers {
    "Content-Language" = en;
    "Content-Length" = 977;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html;charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Tue, 18 Apr 2017 17:23:51 GMT";
    Server = "Apache-Coyote/1.1";
} }
```

When I paste that URL into a browser I get normal JSON response.
Can someone explain to me why returned info is text/html and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I use the code below to ensure that I get JSON responses back from URLs:

**Swift**

```
        var request = URLRequest(url: self.url!)
        request.httpMethod = self.httpMethod
        request.httpBody = body
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
```